# Level of fragmentation of a population

Tags: statistics

Suppose to have a population of $n$ objects. This population is partitioned in $k$ classes. Each class $j$ has a size $j_k$, and since we have a partition of the population $\sum_{j=1}^k=n$.

Exists a formula/method which evaluates the "level of fragmentation" of the population?

To explain this concept, I assume that the level of fragmentation of a population with two classes, such that one as size 99 and the other has size 1, is very low. While, if we have several classes equally sized, then the fragmentation is close to 1.

Comment: It rather depends on whether you see $501$ in class A and $499$ in class B as close to or far away from $500$ in class A, $499$ in class B and $1$ in class $C$ in terms of fragmentation distance

Comment: Good point. I would say that both are equally fragmented, since 1 in class $C$ is considered (in my perspective) such as class $C$ does not exist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a metric should take into account both the number of classes and their relative sizes. Which means that different combinations of "relative sizes/number of classes" may produce the same "degree of fragmentation". The concept of Shannon Entropy could perhaps be usefully adapted here.

Just as an introduction, using your notation, call the total size of the population $S_p= \sum j_k$ then consider the metric

$$F = -\sum_{j=1}^k\left[\frac{j_k}{S_p}\cdot \ln\left(\frac{j_k}{S_p}\right)\right]$$

This metric is *increasing* in the number of classes. Also is increasing as the $\frac{j_k}{S_p}$ are more equal.

It is not a metric bounded in $[0,1]$ but one could easily adapt it to become so.

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing this formula. To be honest, not being bounded in [0,1] is a great limit to compare different levels.